# Why does light have only 3 primary colours and why don't then non primary VIBGYOR colours disperse?

Tags: visible-light, biophysics, vision

While light has so many wavelengths why only 3 colours exist as primary colours? 
Why do some colours disperse while VIBGYOR colours don't (except the primary ones which satisfy the logic as they are basic colours)

Comment: This has already been asked: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24263/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it only red, green and blue that can make up any color through additive mixture?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16638/)

Comment: Related : [What, if anything, makes primary colours distinct?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/187956)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are colors?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24263/)

Comment: What exactly makes mixed colour green light (blue crayon on yellow sheet of paper) and monochromatic light different (I believe that mixed light must be resultant of constructive wave interference of blue light and yellow light)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision

Comment: have a look at the answers to this related question , there is a link in my answer  that show that just with two frequencies one can get color photographs. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15841/can-someone-explain-the-color-pink-to-me/15866#15866 perception of color is a biological effect.

Answer (score 1):

Red, green and blue are called primary colors because when mixed they give us an impression of what we call white light, where "white" means the impression produced in our brain by a range of frequencies as emitted by a black body at a certain temperature, about 6000K, the temperature of the sun surface. In the classic experiment, a spinning disc has three sectors painted RGB but the color appears white. We use the same concept for "white" noise - a continuous range of frequencies, not single frequencies.